# Marketo Integration Webhook possibilities

Tags: webhooks, marketo

we are currently researching about marketo webhook.
In the documentation, there is no explanation about how to trigger webhooks except using Smart Campaign.

Is it possible to trigger a webhook if one browse the our marketo website? And more important, if one filled our formular on the website?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, both of those actions ('Visits Web Page', and 'Fills Out Form') are triggers that can be used in [Smart Campaigns](http://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Create+a+New+Smart+Campaign) to [call a webhook](http://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Use+a+Webhook+in+a+Smart+Campaign).